# Generate overview of objects with only the selected properties

Tags: c#, ascx

I have a user-control which I use throughout my web application. It returns  a `List<Person>` in a table. Currently the properties shown in the list are fixed (by code).

I want to alter the control so it accepts a list of properties which is then used to render the table of those objects (of type `Person`) with only the selected properties visible.

Is this only possible using reflection? What is the best route to accomplish this.

The object:

```
Class Person{
  Name{get;set;}
  Age{get;set;}
  Address{get;set;}
  Role{get;set;}
  AnotherProperty{get;set;}
}
```

The usercontrol just gets a list of Person and shows the results in a plain html table (through a repeater).
Now I want the usercontrol to be customizable in which properties are shown in this html table. I want the usercontrol to be used as followed:

```
<uc:PersonSearchList runat="server" ID="someId" ShowProperties="Name, Address, Role" />
```

or set in code behind:

```
PropertyInfo[] ShowProperties = Person.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can understand more easily your problem and help you

Comment: code added. There isn't much really relevant coding to this question as I need to know how to start first

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a few ways.  I'll show you two.

First, you can create a public property in the user control.  Then, in the code behind, you add your list to the property, like this:

User Controls:

```
Partial Class user_controls_myControl
    Public newList As List(Of myList)

    'do your other suff
end Class
```

ASPX page:

```
dim nameOfList as new List(of String)
me.myControl1.newList = nameOfList
```

Or, you can add it to a public method.

```
Partial Class user_controls_myControl
    Public Sub bindData(ByVal commentList As List(Of CDTrialNotification))
       'attach to your gridviews here
    end sub
end Class
```

ASPX Page:

```
   dim myList as new List(of String)
   me.myControl1.bindData(myList)
```

Comment: this just explains how to bind a list. I want the list that is supplied to the usercontrol to be parsed as html (I know how), but the parsed properties of the object should be able to be decided through a property on the usercontrol.